# TextEdit paragraph numbering - number on paragraph break NOT on line break

Tags: textedit

I need to number my paragraphs but still be able to have un-numbered line breaks inside the paragraph; putting in a soft return (command-return) should work but doesn't; when I re-number the paragraphs through the List Bullets/Numbers menu, it always numbers the line breaks as well as the paragraph breaks.

Has anyone found a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Macs since 1984, and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> has never produced a line break. The correct combination for a line break is <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: My bad, "command-return" was a typo...

In case anyone is interested, I did find the answer. It's Control-Return. That gives a line space but the next plain Return will continue the previous numbering.

Comment: Well, this is interesting. I've always had it work with OPTION+RETURN, but after seeing your comment, I tried CONTROL+RETURN and found that it, too, worked. And then I tried OPTION+RETURN again and found that it did insert a line break without numbering the new line, but it took it _out_ of the numbering scheme altogether and moved it back to the left margin. I could _swear_ it's always worked for me before. So then I tried it in Gmail (because I use it there all the time) and found it wasn't OPTION+RETURN that worked there either – it was SHIFT+RETURN. Sheesh.

Answer (score -1):

The answer, btw, is Control-Return.